# Como criar uma tela de login utilizando o Xamarin?

Tags: mobile, xamarin, login, cross-platform

Qual a melhor maneira para criar uma tela de login utilizando o `Xamarin Studio`? 
Gostaria de fazer um projeto `Cross-Platform`, mas queria ver alguns exemplos de Login com `c#` e de preferência utilizando o `Xamarin`.

Comment: Além das respostas passadas, uma coisa bem interessante é o uso de acesso a redes sociais para o login, segue um exemplo feito com Xamarin.Forms e integrando com Facebook a partir da Web Api deles :) [Exemplo](http://studyxnet.com.br/xamarin-forms-cadastro-de-usuarios-parte-1-autenticacao-com-redes-sociais/) Abraços

Answer (score 2):

**Veja mais detalhes aqui:** [Show me the code](http://xamarin.com/forms)

**UI Design (Individual não cross):** [Andoir e iOS](http://xamarin.com/studio#designers)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2):

Basicamente, existem duas formas:

- Através de uma classe que herde de ContentPage
- Através de um arquivo XAML

A melhor forma será aquela que você tem mais facilidade. Dependendo de como deseja sua página, você terá alguns controles como Label, Entry e Button.

Existe um arquivo muito interessante que aborda um tema específico de autenticação com redes sociais. Neste artigo, é criada uma tela de login. O link está logo abaixo:
http://studyxnet.com.br/consumindo-wcf-no-xamarin-forms/